# Xcode 8 Vary Traits with autolayout issue

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, xcode8, size-classes

Ok I've finally taken the plunge into autolayout using Xcode 8.

I might conceptually have the wrong idea. However I have a view in IB which has 2 labels a button and an imageview dead center in the view with dimensions 300 x 300 for 6plus and 6 devices.

[image]

What I want to do is vary the imageview size for iPhone 5 (SE) so I click Vary for Traits and select height and width then change the values to 150 x 150 click done and the all looks good looking at iphone 5 (SE).

[image]

[image]

Now flicking back to 6plus and 6 its also resized to 150 x 150 but I want the image size to remain as 300 x 300. Again I may have the wrong idea completely.

I thought the whole point in this is that its varying the size dependant on what is selected i.e. varied.

Comment: Varying for traits changes the constraints for different size classes.  The 4 and the 6+ are both the same size class (except the 6+ in landscape which is regular width instead of compact).

Comment: OK so how do i get my image in 6plus and 6 to be 300 x 300 and for iphone 4 to be 150 x 150 in IB. As I said I was expecting that once I am in varying traits mode changing to 150 x150 in the iphone 4 view clicking done would apply 150x150 to the iphone 4 only but it doesnt it applys across all devices. I am sure I may have conceptually the wrong idea but need to get my head around it.

Comment: You can't do that in IB.  Varying for traits only works for varying between size classes and the portrait 4 and 6+ are the same size class.

Comment: Ok if thats the case are  you saying that I need to check for device type and resize programatically in code depending on device? I thought this was the whole point of autolayouts etc...Its also worth mentioning I said iPhone 4 i actually meant iPhone 5 (SE) Ive reedited my question sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, you could do it programmatically and change the constraints based on device type.  It looks like you're just trying to make it sure all your views fit on the screen though?  There's probably a better way to do that than hardcoding the size of the image view.

Comment: Why not consider the image view's size to be a percentage of its container views width. If you give the image view an aspect ratio constraint of 1:1 and then add an equal width constraint from the image view to its container view and set its multiplier to something like 0.75 for a big image or 0.25 for say a profile pic. This can be done completely in IB. This way you get a more consistent UI across all device sizes.

Comment: @Bamsworld nice one that seems to do the trick! I find AutoLayouts very tricky to get your head around and something I've avoided for a long time. Cheers!

Comment: Auto layout can be very powerful and will save you time in the long run. Obviously this logic is not enough for landscape orientation as well. If you support landscape add another constraint to the image view but make this one equal height to its container with a multiplier value set to some value. This may seem counter intuitive but if you lower the priority to say 750 on the equal width and the equal height constraints, auto layout will pick the right one to satisfy! In portrait it will use a percentage of the width and in landscape a percentage of the height instead. All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vary for traits or size class is not used to change autolayout for different devices, rather it is used to change layouts for **Regular and Compact size of (width or height or both)**.Too many devices come under regular width like ipad pro iphone 7 plus, etc.
same iphone se and iphone6 in portrait mode has same width thats is **Compact**.
So when you change for one it changes for both.
When you choose vary for traits and select width+height checkbox it shows some devices in blue box it means all those will be effected.

Better do it programmatically, check device type and set size according to it.

Comment: I've since mastered AutoLayout my understanding originally was wrong. Thanks for the answer though!